# Capture Athena Query Execution Details using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Under CloudWatch, I created a rule to capture Athena Query State Change Event that will (1) write a log to a log group (2) trigger a Lambda function that will capture the Athena Query Execution details and pipe it to a s3 bucket. Point 2 fails as no Athena Query Execution details are piped it to a s3 bucket. Below is the Lambda Function I used:

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

my_config = Config(
        region_name = '<my_region>')
        

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event))
    print("QuertID: " + event['id'])
    
#get query statistics
client = boto3.client('athena', config=my_config)
queries = client.get_query_execution( QueryExecutionId=event['detail']['QueryExecutionId'])
del queries['QueryExecution']['Status']

#saving the query statistics to s3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('<s3_bucket_path>','query_statistics_json/' + event['detail']['QueryExecutionId'])
object.put(Body=str(queries['QueryExecution']))

return 0
```

I used this AWS Documentation as reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/control-limits.html

Answer (score 0):

The body should be of the type binary data.

```
object.put(Body=some binary data)
```

Maybe you can write the `str(queries['QueryExecution']` to a txt file in lambda's `/tmp` directory and upload it.

```
content="String content to write to a new S3 file"
s3.Object('my-bucket-name', '/tmp/newfile.txt').put(Body=content)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just an indentation problem, after line 11, all should be indented...